# Export Sentinal 2 TIFF image from SNAP with all the bands intact?

Tags: sentinel-2, sentinel-snap

I have some Sentinal 2 data from which I need an image of a small area. How do I export that particular image with all the 13 bands intact to a TIFF image using SNAP? I can download 3 bands by viewing RGB and then exporting but I need all the bands intact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is basically a simple `File > Export > 'GeoTiff / BigTiff'` operation, however, it will throw an error as Sentinel-2 bands have various resolutions (10, 20, 60m).

Resample it first, then export.

1. Start `Raster > Geometric Operations > Resampling`. On the `Resampling Parameters` tab, you may choose any of `B2`, `B3`, `B4` for the reference band, to resample all the bands to 10m resolution.
2. Create bands subset by `Raster > Subset`.
3. On the `Product Explorer` pane, click on the subset data to highlight then go to `File > Export > 'GeoTiff / BigTiff'`.

All bands such as the Band 1 (resolution: 60m) will be resampled to 10m in the first step. So this may not give you what you need, if the goal is to stack all the bands as-is.